# Searching for a good keypad

Tags: arduino-nano

I'm wanting to make a keypad for my gragedoor. I found one like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-4-4-Matrix-Array-Matrix-Keyboard-16-Key-Membrane-Switch-Keypad-for-arduino/32380198303.html?spm=2114.01020208.3.1.r4kyIB&s=p&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_10151_10068_5030016_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10177_10110_10136_10137_519_10111_10060_10112_10113_10155_10062_10114_437_10154_10056_10055_10054_10182_10059_303_100031_10099_10078_10079_10103_10073_10102_10096_10123_10189_10052_10053_10142_10107_142_10050_10051,searchweb201603_13,ppcSwitch_5_ppcChannel&btsid=ab793dc3-ba22-4c7e-af4e-fdfb3d180a73) but i don't think it is very waterproof.

Now i'm wondering if someone of you know a good keypad that can be used outdoors and can be connected to a arduino (preferably arduino nano).

Hope you can help.

Edit if found this keypad will i be able to program this one with a arduino?
[link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Pin-Pad-with-Waterproof-terminal-keyboards-ATM-keypads-military-keyboards-IP65-keyboards-weatherproof-keypads-matrix-keypads/32809794485.html?spm=2114.01020208.3.1.8EOZFx&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_3_10152_10065_10151_10068_5030016_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10177_10110_10136_10137_519_10111_10060_10112_10113_10155_10062_10114_437_10154_10056_10055_10054_10182_10059_303_100031_10099_10078_10079_10103_10073_10102_10096_10123_10189_10052_10053_10142_10107_142_10050_10051,searchweb201603_13,ppcSwitch_5_ppcChannel&btsid=490d3b4c-247a-4c78-915a-374ded012e1b&algo_expid=34319a55-04ea-4a5a-b49b-8f921178f0f7-0&algo_pvid=34319a55-04ea-4a5a-b49b-8f921178f0f7)

Comment: Look for the keyword "IP65" in your searches.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking **recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them** are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. [Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: You can connect almost any keypad to an Arduino that does not have active circuitry (by active I mean the keypad has it's own MCU etc.), those with active circuitry might need some more work due to incompatible logic voltages or custom protocols.

Comment: @Avamander could you check out the keypad i just linked in my question? I think this one could work

Comment: It's an USB keyboard by default, Arduinos don't usually do USB. (It's also tad expensive, search more)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The membrane keyboard you have linked (first link) in your question should be water resistant, if not water proof.

We use something similar at my work. You can have the keypad stuck to the outside of the enclosure and then have a rubber seal (or silastic) sealing where the ribbon cable enters the enclosure.

[image: 4x4 membrane keyboard]

You will notice that the ribbon cable pretty much exits the bottom of the keypad. The better ones to get, if you can find them, are the ones where the ribbon cable exits the keypad further away from the edge (see example image below). That way the adhesive backing of the keypad seals the cable entry into the enclosure.

[image: rear membrane keypad]

As far as hooking it up to an Arduino - no problems at all. A 16 key matrix keyboard has 8 connections, 4 for each row and 4 for each column. Every time you press a key, the row and column are shorted together.

[image: internal circuit]

The way I would connect it up is to have the rows connected as inputs and the columns as outputs. One by one I would turn one of the columns on (HIGH) and see which input(s) are reading a HIGH. If it is I know that that key (row and column) is pressed. This method will handle multiple keys pressed at once.

There is an [walk-through tutorial](http://www.instructables.com/id/Connecting-a-4-x-4-Membrane-Keypad-to-an-Arduino/) posted at instructables.com.

The more expensive keypad in your second link and [this one](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3-4-Matrix-rugged-USB-Numeric-IP65-Waterproof-panel-mount-brushed-Metal-Keypad-with-12-full/32293102143.html?spm=2114.40010708.4.6.02kkHy) both have the option of connecting by PS2. There is an Arduino page on connecting and controlling a PS2 keyboard [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PS2Keyboard).

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer but i would like to put this at the front of my house and i dislike the looks of it :). Thats why i found the more expensive one, now i was wondering if i could use that one on a arduino?

Comment: The more expensive one and [this one ](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3-4-Matrix-rugged-USB-Numeric-IP65-Waterproof-panel-mount-brushed-Metal-Keypad-with-12-full/32293102143.html?spm=2114.40010708.4.6.02kkHy) both have the option of connecting by PS2. http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/PS2Keyboard

Comment: Thank you! So every keypad with a ps2 connector "should" work?

Comment: "Should" is the right word. I have never tried it myself. Why not find an old PS2 computer keyboard and give it a try before you buy the keypad.

Comment: This one has a PS2 connector aswel and it has backlit:

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Industrial-waterproof-metal-led-backlit-illuminated-keypads-with-12-keys/32812155017.html?spm=2114.40010208.4.6.MGManS

Comment: That keypad and the original metal one both have the line"Matrix output or standard USB/PS2 output  with controller". Looks like it has the matrix output as well. Worth a try!

Comment: I got it working! :) Now i'll buy the keypad thanks for everything!